# Excel dynamic range in matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my excel worksheet I have a matrix like this:

```
+---+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| * |     A      |   B    |   C    |   D    |   E    |   F    | Col n |
+---+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
| 1 | 01/01/2000 | -1.000 | -1.000 | -1.000 | -1.000 | -1.000 | ...   |
| 2 | 01/02/2000 |        | 1.200  | 500    | 500    | 500    | ...   |
| 3 | 01/03/2001 |        |        | 1.100  | 800    | 800    | ...   |
| 4 | 01/04/2000 |        |        |        | 1.000  | 700    | ...   |
| 5 | 01/05/2000 |        |        |        |        | 900    | ...   |
| 6 | 01/06/2000 |        |        |        |        |        | ...   |
| 7 | 01/07/2000 |        |        |        |        |        | ...   |
+---+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
```

I need a formula for each column (from column 2) with a dynamic range like this:

For Column B:

```
=XIRR(B1:B1,A1:A1)
```

For Column C:

```
=XIRR(C1:C2,A1:A2)
```

For Column D:

```
=XIRR(D1:D3,A1:A3)
```

For Column E:

```
=XIRR(E1:E4,A1:A4)
```

and so on.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Same Formula XIRR and different range for each column, same row.
For example, in cell B8 `=XIRR(B1:B1,A1:A1)`, C8 `=XIRR(C1:C2,A1:A2)`, in cell D8 `=XIRR(D1:D3,A1:A3)` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is:

=XIRR(OFFSET(B$1,0,0,COLUMN()-1),OFFSET($A$1,0,0,COLUMN()-1))

Using `OFFSET` we can specify the number of rows in our offset range... We can use the `COLUMN()` number -1 to get 1 for B, 2 for C etc. We start the offset from an unfixed cell for the values (so it moves along the columns) and a fixed one for dates (so it stays in A)

This formula can just be copied along the cells as far as necessary...

Comment: @paolo-cesari Did this work for you? Feel free to accept the answer!